# Nest Js service layer response not in proper json format

Tags: javascript, nestjs

i am a newbie in nest js, i have a question why nestjs response body return this:

```
signup() {
   return { msg: 'hello'};
}
```

instead of

```
{ 
msg: 'hello' 
}
```

here is my controller code:

```js
/* eslint-disable semi */
import { Controller, Get, Header, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  // POST /auth/signup
  @Post('signup')
  @Header('content-type', 'application/json')
  signup() {
    return this.authService.signup;
  }

  // POST /auth/signin
  @Post('signin')
  @Header('content-type', 'application/json')
  signin() {
    return this.authService.signin;
  }
}
```

and here is my service layer code

```js
/* eslint-disable semi */
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({})
export class AuthService {
  signup() {
    return { msg: 'hello' };
  }

  signin() {
    return 'heiho signin';
  }
}
```

i have googled it everywhere and i dont find any related solution to this problem, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you just return reference of the function, you did not call function use () this to call functions

```js
/* eslint-disable semi */
import { Controller, Get, Header, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  // POST /auth/signup
  @Post('signup')
  @Header('content-type', 'application/json')
  signup() {
    return this.authService.signup();
  }

  // POST /auth/signin
  @Post('signin')
  @Header('content-type', 'application/json')
  signin() {
    return this.authService.signin();
  }
}
```

Comment: aww snap, i trust too much on autocomplete lel, thanks for the solutions!